# Singular vs plural noun following list

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, lists

In the following sentence should *cheese* be singular or plural?

> Pizzeria-style crust topped with herbs, spices, Mozarella, Provolone and Parmesan **cheese**/**cheeses** & pepperoni.

Pepperoni must be the last word.

Comment: Because Mozzarella, Provolone and Parmesan are words that pretty much _only_ mean cheese, you could remove the word altogether.

Comment: All grammar is permissible with pizza - anything goes.

Answer (score 1):

Cheeses because the it applies to Mozarella, Provolone and Parmesan.

> Pizzeria-style crust topped with herbs, spices, Mozarella, Provolone, and Parmesan cheeses, & pepperoni.

You can also add commas when listing more than 2 items, if you like commas.

Answer (score -1):

In order to maintain the parallelism of *herbs, spices, cheeses*, I suggest you reword as follows:

> We offer pizzeria-style crust topped with herbs, spices, cheeses (Mozarella, Provolone, and Parmesan), and of course, pepperoni.

A little more ponderous would be:

> We offer pizzeria-style crust topped with herbs, spices, three cheeses (viz., Mozarella, Provolone, and Parmesan), and of course, pepperoni.

Or you could become really ponderous by naming a few of the herbs and spices, and then separating each sub-list with semi-colons, as follows:

> We offer pizzeria-style crust topped with herbs, such as parsley and basil; spices, such as oregano and garlic; cheeses, such as M, P, and P; and of course, pepperoni.